# Add sub-pages to the navigation menu on a customized Wordpress theme using php, css, and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, navigation, parent-child

I'll try making my story short and concise.

- I work for a small family owned company.
- The web developer parted ways with the company.
- I was appointed to maintain this site:
  [http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/](http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/window-graphics/)
- All I have to do is update content (add subpages and text)

I'm having a super hard time because the theme does not natively support a menu which means everything is hard coded. I tried going to Wordpress > pages > and adding them but it didn't work.
I finally figured out how to show the subpage button under services that says logo (http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/window-graphics/) by adding the page id to this piece of header.php:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&include=8,4,53,51,132,146,152,246'); ?>
                         <!-- <li <?php if (is_category('1')){echo    'class="current_page_item"';}?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?cat=1">BLOG</a></li>-->
```

SO my question is where do I go from there? How do I make the sub-page button I made work? How do I make it so that when the sub-page button is clicked it opens up the page (logos.php) I created? I have been using firebug like crazy and I know, or mostly think, that I have to find wherever it says li.page_item? And I thought it was in a php file and then I thought maybe css but if my fears are correct it's jquery and I have no idea where to even begin. So any help will be most appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is another outlet for WordPress specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

Ya know, it might be easier to just add support for nav menus and replacing that code.

In your `functions.php` file you can `add_theme_support('menus');` ([See Codex on Theme Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support)) anywhere which will allow you to create menus under Appearances -> Menus. You can then replace the `wp_list_pages()` with `wp_nav_menu('Menu Name here');` and it will be much easier to maintain in the long run. If you want to go further you can add a custom walker to include subpages automatically: [View Auto-Submenu Walker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47903/automatic-submenu)

Comment: Thank you for responding. Bare with me please, when you say anywhere is it really anywhere? I added:    <?php add_theme_support( 'nav_menus' ); ?>    and before I could change the header.php the site gave me a parse error or is that because I need to change the header,php and then check the site?

Comment: Sorry, it's just `menus` not `nav_menus` like I previously stated. Usually for formatting purposes I keep my theme supports at the top of my `functions.php` file. You shouldn't need to add any extra `<?php` tags to your functions file for there, usually there is one open at the top.

Comment: Ok. I added both of the codes you told me. Is the old one supposed to disappear? Because it's still there and it kind of doubled the last two pages. http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/commercial-window-film/

Comment: You need to remove `wp_list_pages` and replace it with `wp_nav_menu()` then you can organize your pages under `Appearance -> Menus`

Comment: It was only on two spots and I replaced it. Now the whole menu duplicated :/

Comment: Did you create a Menu under `Appearance -> Menus`? You need to create one there first, then call it via `wp_nav_menu('Menu Name');`

Comment: Yes I created one and saved it as Navigation. It appeared but it was doubled.

Comment: Can you post the header code where the `wp_nav_menu()` is called? maybe it's being looped, you can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: I pasted it as Navigation Duplicated. I don't know if I was supposed to paste it here too, sorry I got confused lol

Comment: lol I'm assuming you're talking about pastebin, can you paste the link?

Comment: Yes sorry lol, I had never heard of pastebin before I kinda didn't know how to use it. here it goes http://pastebin.com/Rc7tnDGp

Comment: With `wp_nav_menu()` you don't need to display it twice for Sub-Navigation, you can just add the Sub-Navigation items to your menu in the admin panel, and it will automatically display as a sub menu. You also don't need to wrap it in `ul` tags, - the function takes care of all that for you. [Check out this short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybow7FytaKw)

Comment: Ok the duplicate disappeared but now the Home button looks tiny? http://pastebin.com/x37yVKns http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/ Also if I click on the subpages nothing happens it just reloads to the parent page :/

Comment: right above your `wp_nav_menu()` you have a link to your homepage, remove that and actually put it into your Nav Menu that you created in the admin panel. As far as the subpages go and default WordPress goes, this really shouldn't happen - do these pages actually exist somewhere? Did you create them? Can you get to them directly? What plugins do you have installed? Sounds like there are really some deeper issues going on. . .

Comment: The pages that do show up right now are set up in php files I believe. And I created one new php files for one of the subpages to see if it showed up but I wasn't sure how to link the subpage button or link to the php page. I also pasted the text under the actual page I created  in Wordpress but nothing shows up. It has the following plugins installed: Akismet, All In One SEO Pack, CataBlog, Contact Form 7, Really Simple CAPTCHA, and WP-PageNavi

Comment: As a regular user you really shouldn't need to make PHP pages for subpages unless they're going to be entirely custom templates or custom queries. If you just want to make a subpage with content you'll need to do it in the admin area. When you create a new page, there's a box on the right side where you can specify a "Page Parent". [Here's a video tutorial](http://youtu.be/8nernhHMuBQ?t=2m10s). No offense but you may want to consider hiring a developer or at least looking for some online training to familiarize yourself more with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a menu. Add the following code to your `functions.php`:

```
function register_RayEames_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Menu Main' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_RayEames_menu' );
```

Then, *nearby* where you want these menus in the code, you include it. Now, your needs may be different from mine, but you need to know that `wp_nav_menu()` has a lot of powerful options available to you. This is based on one of my own sites:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
    'menu'            => 'Menu Main',
    'container'       => false,
//  'container_class' => '',
//  'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'nav',
//  'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
//  'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);
wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

Dive into **[`wp_nav_menu()`'s documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)**.

Once you do that, you can go into the backend of the site and do *Appearance > Menus* to define what goes there - including posts, pages, categories, arbitrary urls, whatever.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I don't know what I did wrong but the sub-pages went all crazy and are at the top now http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/window-graphics/commercial-logos-houston/

Comment: @RayEames Looks like http://tintedadvertisinggraphics.com/wp-content/themes/tinted/css/superfish.css is a missing file in your theme. Probably need to reevaluate how your JavaScript library files are getting added.